# Given linked list pairs swap by changing links

Tags: c, linked-list, swap, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I have a singly linked list where I get the `struct Node* head`, and the return value is `void`. I'd like to swap in pairs without copying the data.

For example, if the input is `2->4->6` then the output is `4->2->6`. But if the input is `2->4->6->7` then the output is `4->2->7->6`.

Here is my code but it doesn't work.

```
void swapPairs(struct Node *head) {
    struct Node *node;
    while (head && head->next) {
        struct Node *nxt = head->next;
        head->next = nxt->next;
        nxt->next = head;
        node->next = nxt;
        node = head;
        head = node->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Parameter for `swapPairs()` must be `struct Node **head` OR you must change the return type from `void` to `struct Node *` so you can return the new head node for assignment to the original list-pointer in the caller.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the pointer to the head (or current) node by reference. Otherwise the function will deal with a copy of the value of the passed pointer. Changing the copy does not influence on the original pointer.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how a function that swaps adjacent nodes can be written.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node *insert( struct Node *head, size_t pos, int data )
{
    if (head == NULL || pos == 0)
    {
        struct Node *new_node = ( struct Node * )malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
        new_node->next = head;
        new_node->data = data;
        head = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        head->next = insert( head->next, pos - 1, data );
    }

    return head;
}

 FILE * display( const struct Node *head, FILE *fp )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d -> ", head->data );
    }
    fputs( "null\n", fp );

    return fp;
}

void swap( struct Node **current )
{
/*
    | A | -> | A | B | -> | B | C |
    head

    Step 1:
    | B |    | A | C |  | B | C |
    head

    Step 2:
    | B |   | A | C |   | B | A |
    head
*/

    //  Step 1:
    struct Node *tmp = *current;
    *current = ( *current )->next;
    tmp->next = ( *current )->next;

    //  Step 2:
    ( *current )->next = tmp;
}

void swapPairs( struct Node **head )
{
    for ( ; *head && ( *head )->next; head = &( *head )->next->next)
    {
        swap( head );
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    const int N = 10;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        head = insert( head, rand() %( i + 1 ), rand() % N );
    }
        
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );

    swapPairs( &head );    

    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
4 -> 7 -> 8 -> 1 -> 4 -> 8 -> 9 -> 0 -> 4 -> 6 -> null

7 -> 4 -> 1 -> 8 -> 8 -> 4 -> 0 -> 9 -> 6 -> 4 -> null
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but the main problem is how i just only got the "struct Node *head", not the **head.. :/

Comment: @AnonymusfromUSA You can not do this if the function has the return type void. Otherwise you need to change the return type to struct Node * and the function body will be more complicated.

Comment: @AnonymusfromUSA It is a general approach if you want to swap something you have to pass that by reference.

Comment: @AnonymusfromUSA it isn't the type of `head` declared in `main()`, it is the parameter type for `swapPairs()` that must be `Node**`. Why? When you pass a pointer (e.g. `Node*`) to a function, the function receives a copy of the pointer with its very own and very different address (it holds the same address as its value), but the pointer address itself isn't the same as the pointer address in `main()`. So any changes you make to the pointer passed as `Node*` is lost on function return. With `Node**` you can operate on the same pointer address from `main()` -- that allows you to swap `head`.